# Allow CORS Magento 2

Tags: magento, next.js, cors

I'm trying to call Magento 2's rest APIs from a local NextJS application, which runs at http://localhost:3000 and I'm getting the following error for every request:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://magento246p3.local/rest/V1/...' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I have installed the following module in Magento `graycore/magento2-cors` and this is my configurations for the module in `app/etc/env.php`

```
...
'system' => [
    'default' => [
        'web' => [
            'api_rest' => [
                'cors_allowed_origins' => 'http://localhost:3000, https://localhost:3000',
                'cors_allowed_methods' => 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
                'cors_allowed_headers' => 'Content-Currency, Store, X-Magento-Cache-Id, X-Captcha, Content-Type, Authorization',
                'cors_max_age' => '86400',
                'cors_allow_credentials' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
...
```

A few days ago, everything worked fine. I don't know what happened but today the error is back.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.